# Liquid filters not working (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid

I'm using Liquid as my templating laguage for price tags that users can download from my site.

Liquid works fine alone, however no custom filters work. They simply doesn't do anything.

Here is an example:

```
$ {{item.primary_offer.subscription.month_price | no_decimal}},- per month
```

this should result in:

```
$ 199,- per month.
```

But the filter does not work so the result is:

```
$ 199.0,- per month.
```

My filters file looks like this:

```
    module LiquidFilters
      include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

      def no_decimal(input)
        number_to_currency(input.to_f, precision: 0)
      end

    end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(LiquidFilters)
```

and my application helper that renders the liquid input looks like this:

```
def liquidize(content, arguments)
  Liquid::Template.parse(content).render(arguments, :filters => [LiquidFilters])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving the LiquidFilters module into the applications helper file (under the ApplicationHelper module).

Everything the suddenly worked.

I do not understand why this made a difference but it did work. If anyone can explain this ill upvote their answer. :)

Comment: This did not work for me, ruby 2.1.5p273 - rails 4.1.8. Liquid just ignores the filter and returns a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the file with this line

```
Liquid::Template.register_filter(LiquidFilters)
```

Has been evaluated before you try to use the filter. You should register the filter for example in `app/initializers/liquid.rb`